# How to detect value change on hidden input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `textarea` in my MVC application where I'm implementing `AspNetSpellCheck`, the debugger tells me that the `textarea` changes to `display: none; visibility: hidden;` and a `div` is generated with `id="abc"` and `class"="pqr"`.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="userid" id="useid" />
```

Also I'm implementing change detection for all text area/other controls....

```
var somethingChanged = false;
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input').change(function() { 
       somethingChanged = true; 
    }); 
});
```

Because the text area becomes hidden, I suppose it doesn't automatically fire the `change()` event. What is the solution to fire the event in above case? Thanks!

**EDIT**

With AspNetSpellCheck, below is my code,

```
  @{  

  ASPNetSpell.Razor.SpellAsYouType mySpell = new ASPNetSpell.Razor.SpellAsYouType();
   mySpell.InstallationPath = ("/Content/ASPNetSpellInclude");
   mySpell.FieldsToSpellCheck = "TextArea1";
}

<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2">bedddly</textarea>
@Html.Raw(mySpell.getHtml())

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="hidden"]').change(function () {
        debugger;
        alert('hi');
        // somethingChanged = true; 
    });
});


 </script>
```

Debugger produce below code, text area hidden and a new DIV construct,

```
 <div tabIndex="null" class="livespell_textarea" id="TextArea1___livespell_proxy">

 <textarea id="TextArea1" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" rows="2" cols="20">
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you dont know when the value is being changed in the textarea you can use `setInterval` to moniter the change

**Eg**

```
  var objTextBox = document.getElementById("your_id");
  oldValue = objTextBox.value;

  function track_change() {
    if (objTextBox.value != oldValue) {
      oldValue = objTextBox.value;
      alert('value of input has changed');
    }
  }

  setInterval(function () {
    track_change()
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: only if you know when the value of the textarea is being changes

Answer (score 15):

With hidden values, you'll need to trigger the change event yourself ala:

```
$('#hiddenInput').val('newval').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. Trigger the event Yourself

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').change(function() { 
     alert('hi');
      // somethingChanged = true; 
});

$('#useid').val("20").change();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/f4ksF/2/)

​

Comment: not work... <div tabIndex="null" class="livespell_textarea" id="TextArea1___livespell_proxy">

<textarea id="TextArea1" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" rows="2" cols="20">