# How to detect form content is changed or not using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've following DOM structure

```
<form name="address_form" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_address_details">
   <input type="hidden" name="latitude" value="52.367659">
   <input type="hidden" name="longitude" value="-0.409539">
   <input type="hidden" name="map_zoom_point"  value="14">
   <input type="text" name="address" value="" value="brington"> //visible element
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>  //visible element
</form>
```

I'm showing above `form` to user with some default input data available in DB below this form I'm showing an OpenLayers map based on `latitude`,`longitude` and `map_zoom_point`.

If user move marker image on OpenLayers map then hidden fields in the above form will be automatically updated, I want capture this change using jQuery. If I use below code,

```
$('form[name=address_form] input').on('change keypress',function() { 
    console.log('something');
 });
```

then `console.log` only prints if user modifies text in address field otherwise it won't print the log message even hidden fields get changed.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Detect value change on hidden input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)

Comment: I think you need to associate the change event to the specific element inside the dom than the form itself.as these changes arent making any changes to the form tag.

Comment: @dreamweiver: He is.  The selector he's using to bind the `change` and `keypress` events is selecting `input` tags.  The issue at hand is that `hidden` form elements don't fire those events.

Comment: The fields are being modified programatically, so the `change` event doesn't fire. You need to trigger it manually when a marker is moved. Presumably this will be covered in the documentation

Comment: @billyonecan: your right

Comment: I had this same problem with the keypress/change event, and started writing a jquery plugin to solve it. Should mostly work, you may have to tweak it tho. [It is here](https://github.com/etaubman/jquery-typeintent)