# jQuery event on value change of input hidden

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I have this input hidden:

```
<input id="j_idt26:myValue" type="hidden" name="j_idt26:myValue" value="0?100?">
```

I want to alert "hey" the first time the value is set and then every time it changes.

I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $hello= $('[id$=myValue]');

    $hello.bind("change load", function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
});
```

But nothing is showing up.
If you can help
Thanks

Comment: How do you change input value? Using val() programatically?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.8.3. It's a JSF Java application so it's programatically.

Comment: Also see this broader question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var $hello= $('[id$="myValue"]');

    $hello.on("change", function(){ //bind() for older jquery version
        alert('hey');
    }).triggerHandler('change'); //could be change() or trigger('change')
});
```

Then, each time you change the value of targeted hidden inputs, trigger handler, e.g:

```
$('#j_idt26:myValue').val('0?200?').triggerHandler('change');
```

That's because onchange event is not fired automatically changing its value programatically.

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer, because I was changing the value programmatically ;)

Answer (score 3):

The change event is fired after the `blur` event on an input, in other words when the input loses focus.  The MDN documentation describes this:

> When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not
>   commited (e.g. after editing the value of  or ).

Since the `input` is of type hidden there will never be any user interaction with the `input` meaning it will not change unless the client side script provided by your site changes it, which will not trigger the change event.

Here are two options:

**Call change() explicitly**

Whenever you modify the value of the hidden input call `.change()` to trigger the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $hello= $('[id$=myValue]');

    $hello.on("change", function(){
        alert('hey');
    });

    $hello.val("Something");
    $hello.change();
});
```

**Just call the code without the handler**

Instead of using the event handler just execute the code you would have within the source.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $hello= $('[id$=myValue]');
    $hello.val("Something");
    alert('hey');
});
```

Another thing I would like to mention is the selector can be scoped a little better.

```
    var $hello= $('input[id$=myValue]');
```

And if your using a new version of jQuery prefer `on` instead of `bind` as shown in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy :

```
$('#my_id').val(myValue).trigger('change');
```

Then you can detect change value on $('#my_id')

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
$(function(){
    var $hello = $('[id$="myValue"]');

    $hello.bind("change load", function(){
        alert('hey');
    });
});
```