# AngularJS POST submitting not working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm learning AngularJS and so far I'm enjoying the framework, but there has been a snag I hit that has really got my wheels spinning and I need some help.

I have a form that I want to submit to some server-side code but when it gets to the server side code, it states that no POST data is present, further more, doing a console.log does nothing to help as whenever I add it, it doesn't show up in my firebug console. I've looked all around and tried everything but am stuck.

My AngularJS Code:

```
var AdminApp = angular.module('AdminApp', ['ui.router']);

// configure our routes
AdminApp.config(function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

$stateProvider.state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'Content/index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });

AdminApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.message = 'test';

//load up our notes.
$http.get('Server/companyNotes.php?companyId=1').success(function(data) {
    $scope.notes = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
});

$scope.processForm = function() {

    $http({
        url: "Server/addNote.php",
        data: $scope.form,
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

    }).success(function(data){

        alert('sent!');

    });
};

});
```

My html form:

```
<form name="addNote" ng-submit="processForm()">
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" ng-model="form.note"></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="companyId" id="companyId" value="1" ng-model="form.companyId">
<input type="hidden" name="added_by" id="added_by" value="Demo User" ng-model="form.added_by">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add Note</button>
</form>
```

I do have ng-app setup on my html tag.

I've tried several things and its simply frustrating me. I hope someone can help me figure this out as I'm must be doing something wrong and not seeing it.

Thanks

EDIT: It seems [Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) is the problem for the case of my textarea not working.

Comment: I suspect that potentially this line could be the problem:
enter code here`data: $.param($scope.form) (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)
Could you provide an example of your server side code?

Comment: I took that out and still I get no POST data sent to the server code.

Comment: I suspect that your issue is with your server side code/setup. Your sample code works fine [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZYtw64jaLqrOYjQ0FIK?p=preview). When I inspect the request in the Network tab of my browser's dev tools, I can see that a payload is parameterized and sent.

Comment: added my server code to question.

Comment: Add an action and method to your form tag and see if that works to rule out Angular issues: `<form name="addNote" ng-submit="processForm()" action="Server/addNote.php" method="post">`

Comment: I'd have a look at the HTTP POST in Chrome's Network Tab in Dev Tools to see exactly what is being sent to your server code. 

If the Request has data and your PHP doesn't then there is a mismatch in what you PHP expects and what was sent.

Comment: it seems that $scope.form is blank but I don't know why that is

Comment: If $scope.form is undefined, you should be seeing a console error for `$.param($scope.form)` but it sounds like you aren't

Comment: actually i did. firefox seems not trigger that but chrome did.

Comment: As long as you enter input into the textarea before submitting, `$scope.form` should not be undefined. Your hidden fields do seem to be wired incorrectly, however.  You might consider populating them in the controller, e.g. `$scope.form.added_by = 'Demo User'`

Comment: I can't as that will be dynamic eventually, currently this is just for testing the basics.

Comment: I discovered something that may be the problem. it seems a jquery plugin is mucking it up, took it off and the textarea is now populated.

Comment: Join me in this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54533/angularjs-post-submitting-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my initial problem.

I was using summernote to allow formatting but it seems that losing the value for angular.

I'll have to look for another tool for that, but I'm happy that I passed that hurdle finally, thanks to everyone who assisted me.

Comment: for anyone that wants to know,I found an angular directive for summernote so that I can still use it
https://github.com/outsideris/angular-summernote

Answer (score 0):

Do you control that server? Is this a cross-origin request?

Add an `error` routine to your requests and check it's outcome

```
$http({
    url: "Server/addNote.php",
    data: $.param($scope.form),
    method: 'POST',
    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

}).success(function(data){

    alert('sent!');

})
  .error(function(reason){
     console.dir(reason);
   });
```

Comment: Yes I do control the server code. its a local request.

Comment: Then also add a logging routine to your server-side code, seeking for request errors. Ensure that the server will respond with a valid answer when a request fails. This will then trigger the `error` routine

Comment: I added a var_dump to my PHP code and it claims my post is blank.

Comment: What does your server say about the request method? `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: it says its a post request.

Comment: Meh. I'm about to give up :(. It is almost like asking if you got the plug plugged in, but are you sure that `$scope.form` is filled? Good luck with the issue, hopefully someone smarter than me will come along

Comment: well it seems that yea $scope.form is not getting populated, so next issue is seeing why that is.

Comment: One thing to look at is your hidden fields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value

Comment: that helped a little but it still claiming its blank

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your serverside code:

```
$aPost = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

And use the $aPost variable as POST array.