# How to add "value" and "ng-value" attributes to an input?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I need to fetch the CSRF token of my Symfony2 form in my `$scope.formData` var, to do this I tried to use a `ng-model` directive but it doesn't work on an hidden field. So i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18446730/1427774) that I'd better use the `ng-value` directive.

So I wrote this twig form theme to rewrite the "hidden" type field:

```
{% block hidden_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = type|default('hidden') %}
         <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %} value="{{ value }}" ng-value="{{ full_name }}" {% endif %}/>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

It produces this HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="data['createpv[_token]']" id="createpv__token" name="createpv[_token]" ng-value="createpv[_token]" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Why is'nt the `value` attribute printed ? It seems to be a conflict with `ng-value` but why ? How can I avoid this ?

Comment: which is the output you're getting now?

Comment: The output i'm getting now is in my question.