# Pass Parameters to hidden input fields in a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

i have a iframe what i have included in a div.

```
<iframe id="uploaderFrame" src="/de-de/[SVO]FileUploader.aspx?projectNo=15" width="250" height="100"></iframe>
```

In this iframe i now have hiden fields.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="projectNo" name="projectNo" id="projectNo" value="{{projectNo}}"/>
```

What is the right way to pass the parameter into the hidden field?

Thx

Comment: Already answered [check here][1] 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value

Comment: I am very sorry. But this don´t works for me.
I have the iframe in a div, both with other Controllers. Now i pass my parameters to my iframe.
I do not have access to my parameters in the iframe. Have i build like the code from 18446359.