# angular.js hidden input data not updating

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble with hidden input. I have this html:

```
<form ng-controller="FormCtrl as a" ng-submit="a.something(a.form)" novalidate>
   <input type="hidden" ng-model="a.form.unitPrice" ng-init="a.form.unitPrice = product.prices[0].price" value="{{a.form.option}}">
...
```

Value of a`.form.unitPrice` is dinamically changing. Controller:

```
this.addToCart = function(a) {
   console.log(a);
   console.log ($scope.a.form.unitPrice);
};
```

Comment: Whats the problem? What are your troubles?

Comment: May be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value

Comment: @Shervin it's not updating a value of that input when I call controller, Cherniv I tried that solution, but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
$scope.$digest();
```

I've noticed also that angular is not updating not visible elements.