# How to get Angular Input Directive Data to Pass to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, paypal

I am using [angular-credit-cards](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards) to create a credit card form. The credit card number has the following setup:

```
<!--... form stuff ...-->
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success': donationForm.ccNumber.$valid}">
  <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card Number</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ccNumber" ng-model="credit_card.number" cc-number cc-eager-type/>
    <div class="input-group-addon">{{donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--... more form stuff ...-->
```

When this form is submitted, it calls a function that creates a Paypal payment. Paypal payments need a credit card type. [angular-credit-cards](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards) determines the credit card type dynamically based on the input that the cc-number directive is a part of and stores it in the input's $ccEagerType. However, how do I get this data from the input and hand it to the controller?

I tried the following:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="credit_card.type" ng-value="donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType"/>
```

But donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType is not being binded to credit_card.type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [readme.md](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards/blob/4c3c3fbc7ed177818b6dd4f6181ad20a7b1d38b5/README.md#card-number-cc-number) of that github project we find this:

> The eagerly matched type will be available as `$ccEagerType` on the model controller.

You can get access to it in your parent controller via form name and input name:

```
$scope.donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType
```

In your case `ccNumber` is the input name. `donationForm` is an inferred name of the form although you haven't posted it in your code.

Ben Drucker requires ngModelController in his custom directive `ccNumber`. Read [AngularJS documentation about ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) about how to handle it being modified from inside a directive.

**EDIT:** *(from the author of angular-credit-cards)*

I'd recommend avoiding the use of a hidden input. You're much better off explicitly adding the value to your request body to PayPal explicitly rather than implicitly binding it.

Also, you should consider using `$ccType` for full cards. Eager typing is intended for displaying issuer logos or other UI features. `$ccType` matches a stricter regex for the full card number. It's possible to achieve a state where `$ccEagerType` is defined but the `<input/>` is invalid and therefore `$ccType` is undefined.

Comment: I saw that, but perhaps I'm misinterpreting what that means. Does that mean that I can 'import' $ccEagerType similar to $scope, $resource, etc? So my controller would look like:

`app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$ccEagerType',..., function ($scope, $resource, $ccEagerType, ...) {...};` When I do that, I get a $injector:unpr error.

Sorry... AngularJS noob here.

Comment: I understand this as simply as `$scope.$ccEagerType` inside your `MyController`. If it is the one that wraps that directive. Btw, there is an example of showing card type in that README.md. Isn't it what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not seeing $ccEagerType under $scope when I check the debugger in my form submit function. I'll try posting an issue on the github repo.

Comment: I am not sure there is an issue

Comment: Author of angular-credit-cards here. Kirill's answer is correct. The type is available as `$scope.donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType`. I'd recommend avoiding the use of a hidden input. You're much better off explicitly adding the value to your request body to PayPal explicitly rather than implicitly binding it.

Comment: Also, you should consider using `$ccType` for full cards. Eager typing is intended for displaying issuer logos or other UI features. `$ccType` matches a stricter regex for the full card number. It's possible to achieve a state where `$ccEagerType` is defined but the `<input/>` is invalid and therefore `$ccType` is `undefined`.

Comment: Revisited this issue and found out there was an error forming the form on my end. Thank you for all the help, it now works. +1's to all.

Comment: Hello, I know this is a late comment but i have the same question.. and i tried the $scope.paymentForm.cardNumber.$ccEagerType in my controller but it get an error of cardName is undefined. my cardName is the name of my input text and my paymentForm is the name of the form

Comment: @VLR, what angular version are you using? can you post any relevant code? a new questioni would suit the situation best

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem with hidden element, `ng-model` binding doesn't work with it.

> Angular model binding didn't pass hidden field while posting a form

Try below code

```
<input type="text" style="display: none;" ng-model="credit_card.type" 
ng-value="donationForm.ccNumber.$ccEagerType"/>
```

[**Refer this SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18446730/2435473)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. Perhaps it has to do with some HTML5 validation that is going on with my form? I have the novalidate attribute on the form at the moment.