# AngularJS not sending hidden input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get data from my form in AngularJS, this all works fine except for the field I did not type anything in. I changed the field from hidden to text, but both do not work, however if you inspect element you can see the correct value in it. Here's my HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="postMessageCtrl as Ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="processMessage()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="formData.message">


            a{{data.receiver.id}}a
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.receiver" ng-value="data.receiver.id" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnq-lg btn-block">Verzenden</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's my controller:

```
app.controller('postMessageCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, localStorageService) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    //$scope.formData = localStorageService.get('userKey');

    $scope.formData = {
        key: localStorageService.get('userKey'),
        message: '',
        receiver: ''
    };

    console.log($scope.formData);
});
```

The key and message are filled correctly, but the receiver id is not. any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please add the implementation of `processMessage()`?

Comment: processmessage is below the console.log(formdata), i quit the code right after the console.log

Comment: I personally don't see the need to submit with AngularJS, because your data object is always loaded correctly due to two-way binding anyway. Just execute a `Save()` function on button click. May help you avoid complexity.

Comment: I'm new to angular....i don't really understand how to do that

Comment: You can simply use ngInit directive for this, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the answer [AngularJS does not send hidden field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value):

You cannot use double binding with hidden field. The solution is to use brackets:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someData" value="{{data}}" /> {{data}}
```

See this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2574

Since Angular 1.2, you can use `ng-value` directive to bind an expression to the value attribute of input. This directive should be used with input radio or checkbox but works well with hidden input.

Here is the solution using ng-value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-value="data" />
```

**Update**:

Another solution could be to directly set the value in `$scope.formData` rather using the `hidden input` field when you are initializing it:

```
$scope.formData = {};
//$scope.formData = localStorageService.get('userKey');

$scope.formData = {
    key: localStorageService.get('userKey'),
    message: '',
    receiver: ''
};

$scope.formData.receiver = $scope.data.receiver.id  // Set the value directly in your `formData` since you are using Angular;
console.log($scope.formData);
```

Comment: aint i doing exactly what you say here....? im using ng value, cause i already read that post.

Comment: But you are using `ng-model` along with the `ng-value`. Can you please remove that and try again.

Comment: Okay, lets take a step back. How are you populating value in `$scope.data.receiver.id`?

Comment: i just put everything in scope.formdata, the key is filled through localstorageservice, and the message + receiver are filled through the form.

Comment: The problem is that this way data will never bind to model which OP needs. Plus ngValue doesn't make sense without ngModel. And even if you add ngModel it will still not work because ngValue is intended for radio buttons and option elements within selectboxes.

Comment: That updated version gives me an error cannot read property of id undefined

Comment: I wrote that just an example. I wanted you to put the actual line there about how you are getting the actual value in `data.receiver.id` which you have written in your HTML hidden element.

Comment: Yes @NickAudenaerde That's what I asked in my previous comments that how are you getting value in `$scope.data.receiver.id` then you said you filled through local storage. I wanted to fill the value from the local storage in the controller itself (as I've mentioned in the controller) rather doing it in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use `ngInit` directive:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" 
    ng-model="formData.receiver" 
    ng-init="formData.receiver = data.receiver.id" />
```

Comment: that leaves me with receiver undefined in the console.log

Comment: Where data object comes from?

Comment: from this line:  <li ng-repeat="message in messages | searchForMessage:searchString" ng-init="data.receiver=messages[0].sender">

Answer (score 0):

Avoid submit complexion by just handling things with a function call on a button click, like on this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfSHUnW6QEsq8OkRFyrw?p=preview).

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="postMessageCtrl as Ctrl">
  <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="messageInput">
          <button ng-click="Add()">Add</button>
          <p></p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnq-lg btn-block" ng-click="Send()">Send</button>
      </div>
      <p></p>
      <b>Messages</b>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in formData.messages">{{message}}</li>
      </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
app.controller("postMessageCtrl", [
      "$scope",
      "$http",
      function($scope, $http){
        var self = {};

        $scope.messageInput = '';

        $scope.formData = {
            key: 'someUserKey',
            messages: [],
            receiver: null
        };

        $scope.Add = function(){
          console.log($scope.messageInput);
          if($scope.messageInput.length > 0) {
            $scope.formData.messages.push($scope.messageInput);
          }
        };

        $scope.Send = function() {
          console.log($scope.formData);

          $http.post("/somehost/action/", $scope.Person).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;
          });
        };
}]);
```

The sample will have a 400 bad request error in console, because the url used is obviously not going to work, but the principle is correct.

This way you don't even need to add hidden fields, because they aren't needed (you always have their value from `$scope.Person`).

**Conclusion:**

There are 2 things that didn't make sense from your original question:

***a{{data.receiver.id}}a***

You should use ***formData*** here, *data* isn't defined.

***JSON is incorrect***

Receiver doesn't contain `id`, given your sample code, it should be defined like so:

```
$scope.formData = {
        key: localStorageService.get('userKey'),
        message: '',
        receiver: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'SomeReceiver'
        }
    };
```

So if your receiver is set like this:

```
$scope.formData.receiver = $scope.formData.messages[0].receiver;
```

You will need to implement some way of providing that receiver through messages[0];

You'll notice that the `receiver` becomes an `Object` in the console log.

Comment: i followed your example 100% now, but now it still shows me the hidden field is empty.

Comment: a{{data.receiver.id}}a this var is showing the variable on screen, so i am sure i got the correct id. a{{data.receiver.id}}a <-- is the id i need.

Comment: I know, it just won't work because _data_ isn't defined, see my answer.

Comment: isnt data defined here?  <li ng-repeat="message in messages | searchForMessage:searchString" ng-init="data.receiver=messages[0].sender">

Comment: It isn't defined in your controller, given the code you provided. It's just not there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97284/discussion-between-nick-audenaerde-and-spikee).