# how to update form hidden data before submssion in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I have my model variables already bound to some hidden input fields in a form.

When the user hits the submit button, I try to update these fields by updating the corresponding bound model variables but they do not change (I noticed that when dumping the request on the server, I always receive the old data), also I noticed that every thing works O.K when I use normal text inputs rather than hidden inputs

Here is my code:

*Form*

```
<form name="bla bla" action="bla bla" method="post" ng-submit="updateForm()"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="token" ng-model= "extra.token" />
  <input type="hidden" name="filters" ng-model="extra.filters" />
  <button type="submit">
    submit form
  </button>
</form>
```

*Controller*

```js
var app = angular.module(... // bla bla

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', ctrlDef]);

function ctrlDef($scope) {
  $scope.extra = {};
  $scope.extra.token = '';
  $scope.extra.filters = '';

  $scope.updateForm = function() {
      $scope.extra.token = 'test1';
      $scope.extra.filters = 'test2';
  };
}
```

Comment: Do you want to reload the screen on form submit? Because if you use form with action attribute, it will reload the page. Is this the requirement or you can fire POST XHR call?

Comment: @ShripalSoni no, actually the form submits to a hidden `iframe` which in turns uses the hidden data to generate a downloadable file

Comment: instead of type="hidden" have you tried ng-hide="true" and type="text"

Comment: @Harbinger nice idea, it solves my problem :) but I wonder if there is a way to use hidden inputs ? [text inputs with `ng-hide='1'` causes some flickers (they are shown while the template is rendered and hidden later)]

Comment: Looks like this should answer your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value

Comment: @Harbinger hell yeah \^^^/

Comment: haha, goodluck and have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ngSubmit will reliably be run before the POST request if you use the standard HTML form attributes (`method`, `action`, etc). A better idea would be to use the [`$html` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) to send your request. This also has the benefit of being asynchronous, so you shouldn't need a hidden iframe like you do at the moment.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$html', ctrlDef]);

function ctrlDef($scope, $html) {
  $scope.extra = {};
  $scope.extra.token = '';
  $scope.extra.filters = '';

  $scope.updateForm = function() {
      $scope.extra.token = 'test1';
      $scope.extra.filters = 'test2';

      $http.post(extra, "your post url here").then(function (response) {
          // do stuff with the response here...
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use XHR calls

Comment: Having the regular `action` is intended because the form submits to a hidden `iframe` used in downloading a file in the same page

Comment: I don't see how this couldn't be achieved just as easily with a XHR - that said, I don't know your codebase, so I could be wrong!

Comment: The response is a file, if there is a way to download a file in JavaScript without external libraries or popup windows then XHRs are welcomed :), anyway thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Ah, yeah, that can be a tricky one if you're not able to use external libraries, not sure how you'd go about that. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!