# Angularjs ng-model not binding to hidden input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to pass form information through hidden input like so:

```
<input type="hidden" required ng-model="formHolder.template[position].itemKey[itr]" ng-value="[[ formItem ]]" />
```

`formItem` can be any string. Errors occur with strings that contain spaces.

**Error**
*angular.js:13708 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Line' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Subject Line] starting at [Line].*

Is `ng-value` expecting a certain type?

Comment: ng-model doesn't work on hidden input

Comment: Here you can find explanation of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `ng-model` doesn't work on `hidden inputs`, so you can just use [**`ngValue`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) to achieve what you want.

The problem is that you're using the incorrect *syntax* on `ngValue` directive.

Here's an **example**:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="Type value to hidden input">
  <input type="hidden" ng-value="value">
  <hr>
  Value of input hidden (or check it in console):
  <pre ng-bind="value"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you're looking for: [AngularJS does not send hidden field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value)

Specifically, you can bind the data from angular to the normal HTML value tag as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someData" value="{{data}}" />
```