# <input type="hidden"> does not send values to REST

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, rest

My project's logic is this.

1. I have an `HTML form` with a `<select multiple>` inside that contains a list of `String`
2. With an Angular.js function I fill a `event-dialog-controller.js` variable with selected `String`
3. I take that variable called `vm.usernames` and I set it as value of an `<input type="hidden">`
4. I call a `REST` service with form's data using `Spring`
5. `Spring` automatically converts the input in an object of `Event` class
6. What I see in the end is that object

My issue is that the field that should get the `vm.usernames` value is empty in my `REST`. I checked up if `vm.usernames` is correct when I call the form (using `console.log(vm.usernames)`), it's correct.

How could I fix this problem?

`HTML` code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="field_attendeestoparse">{{vm.usernames}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" multiple ng-model="vm.attendeesToParse" ng-change="vm.selectUsernames(vm.attendeesToParse)"
                    ng-options="customUser as customUser.username for customUser in vm.customusers | orderBy:'id' ">
    </select>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="attendees" id="field_attendees" ng-model="vm.event.attendees" ng-value="vm.usernames" />

</div>
```

I don't paste here my Angular function because I am sure that it does what it has to do.

A little note. If I use an `<input type="text">` with the same attributes as `<input type="hidden">` and I insert values from keyboard, it works perfectly. I don't know why that hidden does not send that value.

All the other `Event`'s fields work perfectly.

I know I am missing something, please help me!

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446359/angularjs-does-not-send-hidden-field-value?

Comment: why `ng-model` in hidden input.

Comment: @Beginner yes, I didn't solve with it.
I set the same `ng-model` that input text worked with.

Comment: remove `ng-model="vm.event.attendees" `. it should work.

Comment: I've just tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I **finally** solved the problem. It's a pleasure to share the solution, maybe it should be helpful for someone.

I created a new `<input type="text" disabled>`, with Angular.js' function I fill it with selected options and then I send the form.
In other words, when I click on options they are automatically set as values in input text.

It works really fine, maybe it's not the best semantic solution but it solves the problem and works, so I think to use this version of code.

`HTML` code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="field_attendees">Attendees</label>
    <select class="form-control" multiple ng-model="vm.attendeesToParse" ng-change="vm.selectUsernames(vm.attendeesToParse)"
                    ng-options="customUser as customUser.username for customUser in vm.customusers | orderBy:'id' ">
    </select>
    </br>
    <input disabled type="text" class="form-control" name="attendees" ng-model="vm.event.attendees" id="field_attendees" />
</div>
```

`angular.js` controller:

```
$scope.usernames = '';
    vm.selectUsernames = function(model) {
        $scope.usernames = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
            $scope.usernames += model[i].username + " ";
        }
        vm.event.attendees = $scope.usernames;
};
```