# change event not firing in hidden field jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden field 'Edit-WorkOrderId'.

```
  function fn_formCreated(event, data) {
        $("#Edit-WorkOrderId").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#Edit-ProductionStageId option[value='-1']").attr("selected", "selected");
                $("#Edit-ProductionStageId").attr("disabled", true)
                    .closest("div.jtable-input-field-container")
                    .removeClass("mandatory");
            } else {
                $("#Edit-ProductionStageId").removeAttr("disabled")
                    .closest("div.jtable-input-field-container")
                    .addClass("mandatory");
                fn_GetWorkOrderDeatils();
            }
        });
        if (data.formType == "create") {
            $("#Edit-WorkOrderId").trigger("change");
            fn_GetBusinessUnit();
        }
    }
```

The change event did not worked when the value changed.
Thanks Advance.

Comment: `$("#Edit-WorkOrderId").on('input change', function() {` try with this.

Comment: Refer to the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your code. Check your if statement.

Comment: ^ and the console too.

Comment: If fn_formCreated function called more than once, you don't wanna put change event in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the change event like below supposing Edit-WorkOrderId is the ID of the field

```
$('#Edit-WorkOrderId').on('change', function() {
    //do something;
});

function fn_formCreated(event, data) {
   // do something.
   if (data.formType == "create") {
        $("#Edit-WorkOrderId").trigger("change");
        fn_GetBusinessUnit();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the change binding in the `$(document).ready(function{})` call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Edit-WorkOrderId").on('change',function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $("#Edit-ProductionStageId option[value='-1']").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#Edit-ProductionStageId").attr("disabled", true)
                .closest("div.jtable-input-field-container")
                .removeClass("mandatory");
        } else {
            $("#Edit-ProductionStageId").removeAttr("disabled")
                .closest("div.jtable-input-field-container")
                .addClass("mandatory");
            fn_GetWorkOrderDeatils();
        }
    });
})

function fn_formCreated(event, data) {
    if (data.formType == "create") {
        $("#Edit-WorkOrderId").trigger("change");
        fn_GetBusinessUnit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
$('#Edit-WorkOrderId').on('input change', function() {
  if (this.value === '') {
    alert('no value');
  } else {
    alert(this.value);
  }
}).change();

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#Edit-WorkOrderId').val('newValue in timeout.').trigger('change');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' id='Edit-WorkOrderId' value=''>
```

You need to trigger the change whenever you are updating the value.

some notes:

1. You are binding `change` event in a function.
2. When you call this function it registers the change event only. does not fire it.
3. You need to put your change event inside doc ready.

Comment: Thank you @jai , It's working fine.