# jquery on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that updates the result of a textbox dynamically, then that textbox executes based on that value.

```
  <script>
  function updatemykad(mykad) {
  $('#asd3').val(mykad);
  }
  </script>
```

The textbox loads on, on change, on paste. But it doesn't execute from the dynamically inputted value.

```
    $('input#asd3').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {
   console.log(this.value);
    var $q = $(this);
    if($q.val.length == 12){
    ....
```

Comment: You have to manually trigger handler or event, once you changed value dynamically

Comment: you need to trigger the handle like this $('#asd3').val(mykad).trigger("change")

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I guess you meant `trigger("input")` :) But i'm sure OP get the idea

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you, that did the trick! :)

Comment: @A.Wolff trigger("change") also invoke the change event

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/why-does-the-jquery-change-event-not-trigger-when-i-set-the-value-of-a-select-us

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field

Google before posting question..

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger change function when change value.

```
<script>
  function updatemykad(mykad) {
  $('#asd3').val(mykad);
  $('input#asd3').trigger("change");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok but regarding OP posted code, he is binding `'input propertychange'` events, not `change`