# How to POST Jquery Ajax When a hidden input value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to post an AJAX Request when a hidden input value change ?.
The value in hidden input is always change because of Jquery autocomplete.
I tried `$("#id_pt_asal").change(function(event){` but nothing post on console log.
is there any way how to do it ?

Here the HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_pt_asal" id="id_pt_asal" value="" />
```

Here the AJAX script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_pt_asal").change(function(event) {
    var formData = {
      'id_pt_asal': $('input[name=id_pt_asal]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?=base_url()?>akademik/prodi_pindah',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      encode: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.hasil_prodi == true) {
        $("#id_prodi_asal").html(data.html);
      }
    })

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: how you add value in input type hidden?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)

Comment: Yes i understand your question but when and how you fillup the value of hidden type?

Comment: by using jquery autocomplete on different non-hidden input.

Comment: Value change in hidden elements won't fire a change event. Please check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @SLePort thx, I have tried that solution. But still not working. Where should I put the trigger on my code ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to get element of Jquery autocomplete. I assume your jquery autocomplete input given id is `txt`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt").on("keypress",function(){
        //$("#id_pt_asal").val($(this).val());
        $("#id_pt_asal").trigger('change');
    });
   $("#id_pt_asal").on("change",function(event){
     console.log(event);
    //ajax call
   });
});
```