# on change event not working when input type is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

I have changed this hidden value by another event. Hidden value 
changed properly, but onchange event not working (Event not firing);

```js
$(document).on('change', '.endDate', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="endDate" id="endDateID" type="hidden" class="form- 
        control required bdpicker_hidden_input">
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field) it might help you

Comment: You should review you query-selector (second argument).

Comment: Either add a `class="endDate"` or change selector to `'[name=endDate]'`or `'#endateID'`

Answer (score 0):

You did not set class `endDate`, to trigger change event on hidden fields, you need add `.trigger('change');` after set value.

```
$(".endDate").val(1).trigger('change');
```

```js
/*
$(".endDate").change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
})
*/
$(document).on('change', '.endDate', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
$(".endDate").val(1).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <input name="endDate" id="endDateID" type="hidden" class="form- 
    control endDate required bdpicker_hidden_input">    
</html>

<script>

</script>
```