# Hide or show div based on value of hidden input field on change

Tags: jquery, html

Disclaimer: I do not really know how to use jquery (or do many other things).

I have a dropdown menu that populates from a database, and based on the dropdown selection fills a few hidden input fields. After choosing an option in the dropdown, this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="suporlochtml" id="suporlochtml"/>
```

changes to...

```
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="suporlochtml" id="suporlochtml" value="local"/>
```

... which is working as intended.

I want to be able to show or hide a div on the page based on the value of that hidden field. For now, the value could be either "superior" or "local"

After reading this: [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)  I'm under the impression that it requires extra code to detect a change to a hidden input field.

Based on that, here's what I'm trying:

```
<script>

function setUserID(myValue) {
     $('#suporlochtml').val(myValue)
         .trigger('change');
}

$('#suporlochtml').change(function(){
    if ($('#suporlochtml').val() == "local") {   
        $("#superiorcourt").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#superiorcourt").show();
    }
});

</script>
```

I want to show this div when "superior" is the value in the hidden field:

```
<div class="superiorcourt" id="superiorcourt">
</div>
```

And I want to show this div when "local" is the value in the hidden field:

```
<div class="localcourt" id="localcourt">
</div>
```

Right now nothing happens when the dropdown (and therefore the hidden field value) changes. Both divs are still displayed.

Since I don't really know how to use jquery/javascript, I don't know if it's a syntax error or if this isn't possible. I am able to achieve the desired effect when I detect the change of the dropdown the user controls directly with some code involving this:

```
 $("select").change(function(){
```

but if I can figure out how to do it with that hidden field value it will save a ton of work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can initially hide the two `divs` like this:

```
.superiorcourt,
.localcourt {
opacity: 0;
}

.superiorcourt.show,
.localcourt.show, {
opacity: 1;
}
```

You can grab the value from the `input` like this:

```
let suporlochtmlValue = document.querySelector('[name="suporlochtml"]').value;
```

Once you have the value you can add the class `.show` to the respective `div`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(suporlochtmlValue + 'court').classList.add('show');
```

**Working Example:**

```js
let suporlochtml = document.querySelector('[name="suporlochtml"]');

function showDiv() {
document.getElementsByClassName('superiorcourt')[0].classList.remove('show');        document.getElementsByClassName('localcourt')[0].classList.remove('show');
    document.getElementsByClassName(suporlochtml.value + 'court')[0].classList.add('show');
}

suporlochtml.addEventListener('change', showDiv, false);
```

```css
form, div {
float: left;
margin-right: 12px;
}

div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.superiorcourt,
.localcourt {
opacity: 0;
}

.superiorcourt.show,
.localcourt.show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
<select name="suporlochtml">
<option value="initial">Initial</option>
<option value="local">Local</option>
<option value="superior">Superior</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="superiorcourt">Superior<br />Court</div>
<div class="localcourt">Local<br />Court</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see your dropdown related logic as well, because there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your code for showing/hiding the div, just made some minor improvements, see:

```js
function setUserID(myValue) {
    $('#suporlochtml').val(myValue).trigger('change');
}

// just to mimic your dropdown
$('.justfordemo').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#suporlochtml').val() === 'local') {
        setUserID('superior');
    } else {
        setUserID('local');
    }
});

$('#suporlochtml').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'local') {   
        $("#superiorcourt").hide();
    } else {
        $("#superiorcourt").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="suporlochtml" id="suporlochtml" />

<!-- just to mimic your dropdown -->
<button class="justfordemo" type="button">Toggle hidden value</button>

<div class="localcourt" id="localcourt">
  Local Court
</div>

<div class="superiorcourt" id="superiorcourt" style="display: none;">
  Superior Court
</div>
```

but maybe your logic for the dropdown is incorrect and does not set the value on the hidden input properly?