# Adding an Event Listener to a Hidden Input type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to add an event listener to a hidden input element.

I've tried:

```
document.querySelector('#myDate').addEventListener('change', foo);
```

Where foo is a function that I want to call on change.

I am aware that **jQuery** does not by default trigger change and I've also looked at the site's source good and the website has not used `.change()` or `.trigger()` but only uses `.val()` whenever they're trying to update the value of the hidden element. I've also tried the different methods laid out in [jQuery - Detect value change on hidden input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field)
 but that didn't help either.

My HTML element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="31-DEC-2017">
```

I've also tried adding an event listener to each date element in my calendar which is basically a table and each date is a td element. But that failed too.

**Edit:**

It seems as if most of you have misinterpreted what my end goal is, I am sorry about not conveying clearly what I wanted to do. I simply want to add a listener to my hidden input element, so that whenever the `value` attribute of my element is changed, I trigger a function.

Comment: `change` events are only triggered when the user changes an input, not when it's changed by code. The user can't edit a hidden input.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define getters and setters for the `value` property of the `input` so you are notified every time the property is set.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myDate");
var value = input.value;
Object.defineProperty(input, "value", {
    set(newValue) {
        console.log("Value changed to", newValue);
        value = newValue;
    },
    get(){
        return value;
    }
});
$('#changeValue').click(function(e){
  $('#myDate').val($('#newValue').val());
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="31-DEC-2017">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="newValue">
<button id="changeValue">Change Value!</button>
```

You can also use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myDate");
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    if(mutations[0].attributeName == "value") {  
        $(input).change();
    }
});
observer.observe(input, {
    attributes: true
});
$(input).change(function(e){
    console.log("Value changed to", $(this).val());
});
$('#changeValue').click(function(e){
  $('#myDate').val($('#newValue').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="31-DEC-2017">
<input id="newValue">
<button id="changeValue">Change Value!</button>
```

Comment: I was not really looking for a way to set and get the value, I wanted to listen to any changes to the 'value' attribute of my hidden input element

Comment: @street_jesus That's exactly what my answer does: it allows you to be notified every time the `value` attribute is programmatically modified.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear how you are changing the value of hidden filed as it is hidden, and what is perupse of that, but you can use `bind DOMSubtreeModified` witch will track any changes in DOM element and its subtree.

```js
var val= $("#myDate").val();
console.log(val);

$("#myDate").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {

// call your function

var val= $("#myDate").val();
console.log("changed");
console.log(val);
});


$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#myDate").val("21-DEC-2017");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" id="myDate" value="31-DEC-2017">

<button id="add">add diffrent value</button>
```

Comment: My goal is to add a listener that triggers a function whenever the `value` attribute of my element is changed.

Comment: @street_jesus Both of this answers do exactly what you asked for.